# Coldfusion dynamic output of Bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, coldfusion, tabs

Can anyone tell me why this code for bootstrap tabs doesn't work? The tabs are visible and mouse over in the normal way, but nothing happens when I click on them?

```
    <div role="tabpanel">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-       controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <cfoutput query="lessons" group="lesson_date">
    <cfset day = #DatePart('d', lesson_date)#>  
         <li role="presentation"><a href="###day##" aria-controls="##day#"   role="tab" data-toggle="tab">#DateFormat(lesson_date, 'ddddd')#,   #DateFormat(lesson_date, 'd')# #DateFormat(lesson_date, 'mmmm')#</a></li>
     </cfoutput>    
      </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>    
        <cfoutput query="lessons" group="lesson_date">
        <cfset day = #DatePart('d', lesson_date)#> 
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="#day#">test</div>
        </cfoutput>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Viewing the source code it looks ok with the relevant id's being shown...

```
    <div role="tabpanel">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria- controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>

        <li role="presentation"><a href="#22 aria-controls=22" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Friday, 22 May</a></li>

        <li role="presentation"><a href="#23 aria-controls=23" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Saturday, 23 May</a></li>

        <li role="presentation"><a href="#24 aria-controls=24" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sunday, 24 May</a></li>

       </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
       <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>    

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="22">test</div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="23">test</div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="24">test</div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

`<a href="###day##" aria-controls="##day#"...`

You have too many hashes after the first variable. Should be:

`<a href="###day#" aria-controls="#day#"...`

This should then output a functional link:

`<li role="presentation"><a href="#22" aria-controls="22"...`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but doing as you suggest throws the error "Invalid CFML construct found on line 215 at column 76." As I have it at the moment you can see in the source code that the href and aria-controls   appear to be outputting correctly.

Comment: I fixed the typo in my code,  sorry. The href and aria-controls aren't outputting correctly in your source.  The href isn't closed properly and the aria-controls aren't opening correctly.

Comment: Jesus! I thought i tried every combination of hashes! Thanks a million Antony!

Comment: The double hash you used to create the anchor put you off. When you want to output a hash you escape it by doubling. Depending on your IDE this may confuse syntax highlighters,etc.